# Как сделать поля закрытыми?

Tags: c++

Есть программа вычисления расстояния между точками. Как переделать её так, чтобы поля были закрыты?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Point {
  public:
    double x, y;

    void movex(double move) {
        x += move;
    } void movey(double move) {
        y += move;
    }
    double to0() {
        return sqrt((x * x + y * y));
    }
    double topoint(Point b) {
        return sqrt(((x * x - b.x * b.x) * (x * x - b.x * b.x) + (y * y - b.y * b.y) * (y * y - b.y * b.y)));
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Point a, b;

    double move;
    cout << "Координаты т. А:nx=";
    cin >> a.x;
    cout << "y=";
    cin >> a.y;
    cout << "Координаты т. B:nx=";
    cin >> b.x;
    cout << "y=";
    cin >> b.y;
    cout << "Смещение т. А по оси ох: ";
    cin >> move;
    a.movex(move);

    cout << "Смещение т. А по оси оy: ";
    cin >> move;
    a.movey(move);
    cout << "Смещение т. B по оси ох: ";
    cin >> move;
    b.movex(move);
    cout << "Смещение т. B по оси оy: ";
    cin >> move;
    b.movey(move);
    cout << "Новые координаты точек: A(" << a.x << ";" << a.y;
    cout << ") B(" << b.x << ";" << b.y << ")n";
    cout << "Расстояние от т. А до начала координат: " << a.to0();
    cout << "nРасстояние от т. B до начала координат: " << b.to0();
    cout << "nРасстояние между точками A и B: " << a.topoint(b);
    cout << "nn";
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструктор лучше сделать публичным, а вот поля поместить в секцию private.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <clocale> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

class Point{ 
public:
Point(){x=y=0;}
void cinY(){cin>>y;}
void cinX(){cin>>x;}
double getY(){return y;}
double getX(){return x;}
void movex(double move){x+=move;} 
void movey(double move){y+=move;} 
double to0() 
{return sqrt((x*x+y*y));} 
double topoint (Point b) 
{return sqrt(((x*x-b.x*b.x)*(x*x-b.x*b.x)+(y*y-b.y*b.y)*(y*y-b.y*b.y)));} 
private: 
double x,y;
};

int main(){ 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian"); 
Point a,b;

double move; 
cout<<"Êîîðäèíàòû ò. À:\nx="; a.cinX(); 
cout<<"y="; a.cinY(); 
cout<<"Êîîðäèíàòû ò. B:\nx="; b.cinX(); 
cout<<"y="; b.cinY(); 
cout<<"Ñìåùåíèå ò. À ïî îñè îõ: "; cin>>move; 
a.movex(move);

cout<<"Ñìåùåíèå ò. À ïî îñè îy: "; cin>>move; 
a.movey(move); 
cout<<"Ñìåùåíèå ò. B ïî îñè îõ: "; cin>>move; 
b.movex(move); 
cout<<"Ñìåùåíèå ò. B ïî îñè îy: "; cin>>move; 
b.movey(move); 
cout<<"Íîâûå êîîðäèíàòû òî÷åê: A("<<a.getX()<<";"<<a.getY(); 
cout<<") B("<<b.getX()<<";"<<b.getY()<<")\n"; 
cout<<"Ðàññòîÿíèå îò ò. À äî íà÷àëà êîîðäèíàò: "<<a.to0(); 
cout<<"\nÐàññòîÿíèå îò ò. B äî íà÷àëà êîîðäèíàò: "<<b.to0(); 
cout<<"\nÐàññòîÿíèå ìåæäó òî÷êàìè A è B: "<<a.topoint(b); 
cout<<"\n\n";system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: Как его вообще сделать? Что необходимо поменять в коде?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибища!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Примите пожалуйста ответ, если он вас устроил. Спасибо...

Comment: @Asen Такие геттеры и сеттеры - это очень плохо. Лучше определить нормальные операторы ввода и вывода в поток.

Comment: Еще есть другая точка зрения на этот вопрос:

У обычной точки (`Point`) нет особого состояния или инвариантов. На самом деле это просто упорядоченная пара чисел, и поэтому имеет смысл такая структура:

    struct Point
    {
        double x, y; // по умолчанию - public
    };

А геттеры-сеттеры в такой структуре - это ненужная надстройка, которая только усложняет код.

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Сделать поля `private`. Добавить конструктор для точки от двух чисел `Point(double x, double y)`.

---

Исправленный и отформатированный код:

```
struct Point
{
public:
    Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y)
    {}
    ...
    double topoint(Point b)
    {
        // расстояние до другой точки считалось неправильно
        return sqrt((x - b.x) * (x - b.x) + (y - b.y) * (y - b.y));
    }

private:// обычно в C++ (в отличие от Java) private поля размещают в конце класса
    double x, y;
};
```

---

Еще есть другая точка зрения на этот вопрос:
У обычной точки (Point) нет особого состояния или инвариантов. На самом деле это просто упорядоченная пара чисел, и поэтому имеет смысл такая структура:

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y; // по умолчанию - public
};
```

А геттеры и сеттеры в такой структуре — это ненужная надстройка, которая только усложняет код.

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в этом. Public на Private я изменил, а что далее? Куда пихать конструктор? Помогите пожалуйста. Я обещаю разобраться в этом и обещаю быть очень благодарным.

Comment: @Саша Гаврилов обновил ответ, но рекомендую читать литературу перед отправкой таких вопросов